# AS3 convert ByteArray of ARGB values to RGB uint

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, arrays, bitmapdata, argb

I have a C++ QT application that is sending a ByteArray of ARGB values via a TCP socket. The image is 100 x 100. The problem is that when I read off the ByteArray I can't seem to get the image to display right. I've tried lots of different ways and here is AS3 code that's got me the closest.

```
bitmapData.lock();
for(var x = 0;x<100; x++){
  for(var y = 0;y<100; y++){
    alphaValue = byteArray.readUnsignedByte();
    redValue = byteArray.readUnsignedByte();
    greenValue = byteArray.readUnsignedByte();
    blueValue = byteArray.readUnsignedByte();
    color = redValue << 16 | greenValue << 8 | blueValue;
    bitmapData.setPixel(y,x,color);
  }
}
bitmapData.unlock();
```

I'm just not using the alpha value at the moment because I'm not sure what to do with it. Qt says "The image is stored using a 32-bit RGB format (0xffRRGGBB)." I tried using `readUnsignedInt()` too, but that didn't work either.

Here is what I'm trying to send and what I see on screen.

Sent : [image] Received in Flash [image]

It's close, but not just right. Does anyone have any idea what I may be doing wrong?

Comment: Looks like the channels are scrambled.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Much easier would be to use `readUnsignedInt` instead of multiple calls to `readByte`. Then use `bitmap.setPixel32` instead of `setPixel`. That way you don't have to deconstruct and reconstruct the values.

You might also have to switch the endian-ness (e.g. `byteArray.endian = Endian.LITTLE_ENDIAN`) depending on how it's encoded. I just can't remember off-hand which way around it is, so you can try that if it doesn't work first time.

Comment: I had tried readUnsignedInt with setPixel32 and had similar looking issues. I haven't tried changing to LITTLE_ENDIAN though, I'll try that and get back to you. Thanks.

Comment: byteArray.endian = Endian.LITTLE_ENDIAN; Worked perfectly can't say how good it feels after trying all sorts for hours. Not a lot of info on the endian stuff in documentation, I've done some reading and understand it a bit more now. Thanks.